# Build a dataframe from txt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract some information from the a txt. file (which is named `inf.txt`), to build a dataframe in python. An example of `inf.txt` is this:

```
bene_id_18900    (Variable1, 43)
bene_id_18900    (Variable4, 0)
dtype: object 0
encrypted 723 beneficiary id    (Label1, 43)
encrypted 723 beneficiary id    (Label5, 4)
dtype: object 0
bene_id_18900    (Variable1, 43)
bene_id_18900    (Variable4, 0)
dtype: object 0
from      (Variable4, 95)
from         (VNAME4, 95)
from      (Variable6, 94)
from         (VNAME6, 94)
dtype: object 2
first day on claim billing statement      (Label4, 95)
first day on claim billing statement      (Label6, 94)
dtype: object 2
thru     (Variable4, 140)
thru        (VNAME4, 140)
thru     (Variable6, 142)
thru        (VNAME6, 142)
dtype: object 3
last day on claim billing statement     (Label4, 140)
last day on claim billing statement     (Label6, 142)
dtype: object 3
```

The wanted result is this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6
0   43  na  na  0   4   na
1   na  na  na  na  na  na
2   4   5   na  95  na  94
3   na  na  na  140 na  142
```

The row number is from the number following *dtype: object*, the column number is from the second number in each bracket.

For example, in the first line its (Variable1, 43): it belongs to *dtype: object 0*, so it in the first row; Variable1, so it in the first column.

Another example, in the penultimate line, its (Label6, 142): it belongs to *dtype: object 3*, so it in the third row; Label6, so it in the sixth column.

All these string like "bene_id_18900", "Variable", "Label"  and so on are actually no meaning.

My idea is adding the corresponding row number in the each bracket，so later I can keep all the useful information and delete all the unuseful information. Like this:

```
(1, 43, 0)
(4, 0, 0)
(1, 43, 0)
(5, 4, 0)
(1, 43, 0)
(4, 0, 0)
(4, 95, 1)
(4, 95, 1)
......
......
......
```

My trying, I really have no idea....

```
with open('/Users/xccxken/Dropbox/inf.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content] 
for x in content:
```

Answer (score 0):

let us say you know the no of rows(M) and columns(N) from the text file. a simple parse to get the max dtype and max label(no) variable(no) will get this information.
next create an array of MxN

```
import re
import pandas as pd
# assuming that you have found the max no of rows M and max no of columns N.
M = 4
N = 6
# create MxN list of lists with values 'na'
x = ['na'] * N
data = []
for i in range(M):
    tmp = list(x)
    data.append(tmp)
index_x = -999 # fix for NameError
# data = [x] * M; this does not work since lists are mutable objects

with open('/Users/xccxken/Dropbox/inf.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        if 'dtype' in line:
            # get the x axis index
            index_x = int(line.split(' ')[-1])
        if 'Label' in line:
            # get y axis index
            c = re.search('Label(\d), (\d+)', line)
            index_y = int(c.groups()[0])
            # reduce index_y by 1 as the col names start with 1 and python list is 0 index
            if index_y > 0:
                index_y -= 1
            # get value
            value = int(c.groups()[1])
            if index_x >= 0: # fix the NameError and a logical bug
                # populate the correct x,y location in the list of lists
                data[index_x][index_y] = value
        if 'Variable' in line:
            c = re.search('Variable(\d), (\d+)', line)
            index_y = int(c.groups()[0])
            value = int(c.groups()[1])
            if index_y > 0:
                index_y -= 1
            if index_x >= 0: # fix the NameError and a logical bug
                data[index_x][index_y] = value
# create the col names
cols = range(1, N+1)
# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Hope this helps, this worked for me
i took this as the sample:

```
dtype: object 0
encrypted 723 beneficiary id    (Label1, 43)
encrypted 723 beneficiary id    (Label5, 4)
dtype: object 0
bene_id_18900    (Variable1, 43)
bene_id_18900    (Variable4, 0)
dtype: object 0
from      (Variable4, 95)
from         (VNAME4, 95)
from      (Variable6, 94)
from         (VNAME6, 94)
dtype: object 2
first day on claim billing statement      (Label4, 95)
first day on claim billing statement      (Label6, 94)
dtype: object 2
thru     (Variable4, 140)
thru        (VNAME4, 140)
thru     (Variable6, 142)
thru        (VNAME6, 142)
dtype: object 3
last day on claim billing statement     (Label4, 140)
last day on claim billing statement     (Label6, 142)
dtype: object 3
```

and the output is:

```
    1   2   3    4   5    6
0  43  na  na   95   4   94
1  na  na  na   na  na   na
2  na  na  na  140  na  142
3  na  na  na  140  na  142
```

just fyi, i consider these as valid data too:

```
dtype: object 0
from      (Variable4, 95) # is valid
from         (VNAME4, 95)
from      (Variable6, 94)
from         (VNAME6, 94) # is valid
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I am net to python, i copy the code, but there's a error in line 39, says NameError: name 'index_x' is not defined, please tell me how to fix. thanks!

Comment: hi kkjoe, please check now, it should work. i had not initialised index_x, hence there was NameError (because dtype was not the first line).